# CSS - to mimic iOS, Blackberry OS and AndroidOS?

Tags: css

I'm looking for a set of CSS or scripts which mimic the UI (only the UI) of default applications on the iPhone/iPad, Blackberry and base Android apps?

I have a client who needs the ability to preview content and form pages on the various OS', but in their desktop browser (Chrome, FF, IE(ugh)). Ofcourse, there are dozens and dozens of standalone emulators, but I cannot find any one who may have created CSS or scripts to mimic how these would look, in the browser - e.g. default button stylings, colours, etc. not the logic of the app, but just the way it could look - with the best example I can find being : http://groupaware.mobi/iphone/#_Windows

Anyone with ideas?

thanks!

Comment: +! for a great question.

Comment: http://snippetspace.com for ios

Answer (score 2):

For iOS:

http://code.google.com/p/iphone-universal/

and

http://www.peterhintondesign.co.uk/journal/index.php/iphone-css-template/

which is based on the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but until now I have only been able to find templates regarding the Iphone and not the BlackBerry nor Android UI. (I've tried to find them myself before too.)

A great template for CSS (Photoshop CS4 or higher needed) based on the Iphone is: 
http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/2010/06/14/iphone-gui-psd-v4/

Also the links by tomwadley, especially the prior link, are also quite useful regarding coding and framework.

Answer (score 0):

There's some answers in this book: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596805791/ about creating CSS styles to mimic iOS stuff. Also covers phonegap etc, might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile (JQM): http://jquerymobile.com is a framework which does just that. At its simplest, it renders "standard" html elements as native OS elements for platforms like iOS and Android.

You don't have to use the JQM framework, of course; you could simple take what you need from the CSS that JQM employs. Either inspect the css directly or write a simple test page which loads JQM and inspect the CSS in Firebug or Chrome developer console.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout iUI..probably what you are looking for.
http://www.iui-js.org/index.html

Answer (score 0):

For the android, try this implementation of Holo Light and Dark:  http://vezquex.com/projects/holo-css/